# Dask computes more than necessary during groupby

Tags: python, dataframe, dask

It seems to me that Dask does more work than necessary when using [DataFrame.groupby](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/generated/dask.dataframe.DataFrame.groupby.html).

If I set up some data and want only a subset of the resulting operation,

```py
import dask
df = dask.datasets.timeseries(partition_freq='2W').set_index('id').persist()
task = df.groupby('id')['x'].sum().head(compute=False)
```

Dask seems to want to use all partitions for the computation:

```py
task.visualize(optimize_graph=True, size='8')
```

[image]

Groupby automatically collapses the dataframe into a single partition and I suppose head cannot change the graph retrospectively in that regards.

I hoped that perhaps `split_out` could help this, but that's also not the case.

```py
task = df.groupby('id')['x'].sum(split_out=2).head(compute=False)
task.visualize(optimize_graph=True, size='8')
```

[image]

It therefore seems that in this particular case, Dask does (potentially significantly) more work than necessary.

### Question

My questions thus are

- Is my assessment of the situation correct? Does Dask indeed do much more work? If not, how could I tell?
- If I'm correct, what can I do to tell Dask to only compute what is needed?

My actual problem is of course much more complex, but I'm hoping these toy examples will help illuminate the problems in my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that `map_partitions` is your friend even for groupby-with-index operations!

```py
import dask

# Warning: might be too big, scale according to your machine
df = (dask.datasets.timeseries(end='2002-01-30', partition_freq='2W')
      .set_index('id')
      .persist())

task_a = df.groupby('id')['x'].sum().head(compute=False)
%time task_a.compute()
CPU times: user 22.5 ms, sys: 843 µs, total: 23.3 ms
Wall time: 161 ms

task_b = df.map_partitions(lambda x: x.groupby('id')['x'].sum()).head(compute=False)
%time task_b.compute()
CPU times: user 11.6 ms, sys: 0 ns, total: 11.6 ms
Wall time: 19.6 ms
```

Results in this much more reasonable graph (shown only for the original data with 2 partitions)

[image]

Comment: I see your point. The `map_partitions` does work in this example.